# jquery put delay before running the next loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to put a delay/sleep before running the next loop?
I cant use the $.ajax async false. because the loader wont show up
for each row.

I need to call the next loop after the $.post request is done.

**Code:**

```
$( ".ids:checked" ).each(function() {
    var Id = $(this).val();

    $(".modal_close_btn").hide();

    if(y==count){
        last_request = 1;
    }else{
        last_request = 0;
    }

    $.post("db/delete_test.php", {Id:Id,last_request:last_request},
    function(data){     

        $("td#Id_"+Id).html(data.message);
        if(x==count){
            $(".modal_close_btn").show();
        }

        x++;
    },"json");  
    y++;

});
```

Comment: haven't you tried using settimeout, and why is there a php tag here

Answer (score 0):

$( ".ids:checked" ).each(function() {
   var Id = $(this).val();

```
$(".modal_close_btn").hide();

if(y==count){
    last_request = 1;
}else{
    last_request = 0;
}
setTimeout(function(){ 
$.post("db/delete_test.php", {Id:Id,last_request:last_request},
function(data){     

    $("td#Id_"+Id).html(data.message);
    if(x==count){
        $(".modal_close_btn").show();
    }

    x++;
},"json");  
y++;
}, 3000);//time sleep
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a fundamental misunderstanding of whats going on.

I don't think what you want is a delay. The .each is functioning as a loop, but you have an async call in it. Do you need to wait for the post request to return before calling the next? If so you will need to do something like callback chaining. Basically what will happen is that all of the requests will get sent at once and will return in a random order. You will want to wait for a request to finish before calling the next one if you need for them to appear in order. Or you can do other things dealing with preserving contexts. But your question is fairly vague as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes, I need to call the next loop after the ajax request is done. I cant use the $.ajax async false. cause it kind of hangs the browser.

Comment: Ah yes. Okay so I think what you really want to do is call the next ajax call in the success function.  I can help if you need it with writing the code, but it shouldn't be too bad.